# VBA, Loading the ListBox Display Faster

Tags: excel, vba, forms, listbox

I have this large data set on Excel (50-100 row by 17 column) that I would like to preview after adding a new set of data every time, but I found that it is taking very long time and waste so much performance in loading the `ListBox`. I wonder if there is a way to improve the VBA code to load the `ListBox` faster.

```
    Dim n As Long
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim Prefill_Row As Long
    Dim Last_Row As Long
    Dim Last_Col As Integer
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
   'Set current worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataInput")  'Location of the active worksheet

    Last_Row = [Counta(DataInput!A:A)] 'identifying the last row

    For n = 1 To Last_Row
        xRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, Comment_ColumnNumber).End(xlUp).Row 'how many filled rows
        Prefill_Row = xRow + 1 'find next row to be filled
    
    With frmForm 'frmForm is the name of VBA form

           ...
           ... 'codes to write inputs from VBA form into Excel spreadsheet

          'display windows setting
          .ListBox1.ColumnCount = 17 'Display window setting contains 17 col
          .ListBox1.ColumnHeads = True
          .ListBox1.ColumnWidths = 
        "100,60,60,80,0,80,0,80,80,80,80,100,120,250,150,100,120"

          'display data from the worksheet tab named DataInput using RowSource
           If (Last_Row > 1) Then
              .ListBox1.RowSource = "DataInput!A2:Q" & (Prefill_Row)
           Else
              .ListBox1.RowSource = "DataInput!A2:Q2"         
           End If
    End With
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to keep setting the column count/heads/widths properties every time. Your data set isn't particularly large - are you sure the delay is with the listbox and not the writing to the cells?

Comment: What is the `For n = 1 To Last_Row` doing ?

Comment: ... and where does the loop end? There's no closing `Next` visible in your code fragment @yl129

Comment: @Rory Not 100% sure, but after trying not to run the `ListBox` the delay becomes insignificant

Comment: @CDP1802 @T.M. the `for loop` is to get the row number of the next cell needed to be filled in, reuse the row number to fill inputs onto Excel, and display `ListBox`. The `Next` is after `End With`. It got left out after copying my code over. Possibly, it is the long `for loop` causing the delay?

Comment: In that case it looks like you are setting the `.ListBox1.RowSource` at every iteration of n rather than just once at the end.

Comment: @CDP1802 Cool, it's working very efficient now. Thx for picking that up! I was thinking to use that `for loop` for another feature earlier on but later on abandoned that feature. I guess I should have checked my logic again. Thanks a lot!